# How to re-render in a React Functional Component According to a onChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I would like to reflect a value inside the `div` tag that you choose from the following select tag right after the value changes by `onChange` when you use a React Functional Component, so you can't use `setState` function. Under the prerequisite, how do you call render method (or, re-render the value inside the div) according to the value change? Any idea?

```
<select onChange={foo}>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<div>{value}</div>
```

Comment: Handle state in a parent and pass down an onChange handler and value?

Comment: as far I know if you have state maintained like in redux you can manage state by dispatching actions or if you do not have redux neither you want it then pass a function from parent to child and call that function from child and in that function change your state.

Comment: I don't use Redux, but use just a local variable in the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Maintain the state in the parent component, pass it as props to the functional component to show the value
2. Pass the onChange from parent to functional child component as well.

Like this,

```
function Child({ value, onChange }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={onChange}>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
      <div>{value}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <Child value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution seems to be the best answer for my question. So, I made this the answer. Thank you!